# Github: Search query including wildcard characters

Tags: github

For example, if I want to find where a particular structure is defined inside a given Github repository, I might search `struct struct_name {`, but as `{` is simply ignored from search query, result of `struct struct_name` are displayed. For heavily used structure, it becomes quite difficult to find location of structure definition this way.

I would prefer pulling the repo and grepping the expression, if repo is of reasonably small size, but for large codebase, it might not be viable option.

Any straightforward way?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

`git grep -n 'struct Pool {'`

Otherwise I think there's no way. In the [help page](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#considerations-for-code-search) of Github is said that:

**You can't use the following wildcard characters as part of your search query: . , : ; / \ ` ' " = * ! ? # $ & + ^ | ~ < > ( ) { } [ ]. The search will simply ignore these symbols.**